# Is v-deep an anti-pattern in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, vuejs2, vuejs3

When styling a Vue.js component, you can use `::v-deep` to target CSS classes of nested components, e.g.

```js
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <Child /> <!-- contains .grandchild CSS class -->
  </div>
</template>

// ...

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.parent {
  ::v-deep {
    .grandchild {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

Given that renaming or removing `.grandchild` could break consumers of `Child`, isn't using `v-deep` considered bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on context, it can be esential in cases where you are working with components that you cannot modify directly, e.g. third party components.
In the rest of cases is better to follow best practices such as using props to manage child component styles or using global CSS.

For that reason `::v-deep` should be only used as a last resort when there are no other options.